# how do you read locale information from session?

Tags: java, jsp, internationalization, jstl, locale

The following bit of code sets the Locale from lang param on querystring.

```
<c:if test="${param['lang'] != null}">
    <fmt:setLocale value="${param['lang']}" scope="session"/>
</c:if>
```

How do I now read that variable?

I know its a bit noobish.

I need a bit of conditional logic to display one language link if the local hasn't been set in the session scope using the `fmt:setLocale`, and another if it has been set to a specific locale.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.locale.language == 'en'}"> 
    <a href="link1">Link 1</a> 
</c:if> 
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.locale.language != 'en'}"> 
    <a href="link2">Link 2</a> 
</c:if>
```

Comment: thanks - but is not working in my case. a bit more info on what im doing is on next answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${sessionScope['javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.locale.session'] eq 'en_CY'}">
        a href="?lang=en_GB">English</a>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <a href="?lang=en_CY">Cymraeg</a>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

this works but is there a better way to write?

```
<c:when test="${sessionScope['javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.locale.session'] eq 'en_CY'}">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${pageContext.response.locale eq 'en_CY'}">
        <a href="?lang=en_GB">English</a>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <a href="?lang=en_CY">Cymraeg</a>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

this works only on the page itslef.

but because its reading from the pageContext, it will not work on other pages by reading it from the sessionScope (where it is being set by the `fmt:setLocale`).

How would i read it from the sessionScope?